# My animation that I made in MoonAnimator won't work

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

I'm making a game with my friend on team create. I made an animation and I saved it under the group's ownership. When I try to play it, however, it gives me this message: "Failed to load animation: rbxassetid://14202555431 (x2)" the animation is a child of the script.

```
local animation = script:WaitForChild("Animation")
local humanoid = game.Workspace.JumpscareSanty.Humanoid
local dance = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
while true do
dance:Play()
wait(1)
end
```